Can we disable SQL Telemetry CEIP service?
My team is thinking of disabling CEIP service altogether from prod servers until we found out that Microsoft advises opting out of data collection (via SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting) instead of disabling it.
I found following statement in remarks of Local audit for SQL Server usage and diagnostic data collection (CEIP).
When they say, I quote

Remarks:
Removing or disabling the SQL CEIP service is not supported.
Removing the SQL CEIP resources from the Cluster Group is not supported.
Opting out of SQL Server usage and diagnostic data collection is supported, but the service can't be removed or disabled. To opt out of the data collection, see Turning local audit on or off

do they mean
we won't be able to get Microsoft support or are they saying it is going to affect database performance (CLUSTER or not) right now or later in future.
I have disabled it in one of the standalone dev servers, but it has not caused any problems in database engine performance so far(nothing noticeable).

It means it's not supposed, so anything can happen, from server running faster, slower, your computer melts or nothing at all

this has some info ,that might help..https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/10/what-is-the-sql-server-ceip-service/
